# How to prevent SegmentedControl index from changing, based upon confirmation dialog box?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a SegmentedControl. When the user clicks on it, a confirmation dialog box appears, asking if they wish to change the value. If they click "Cancel", I want to cancel the change to the SegmentedControl value.

This is a code segment I have:

```
@IBAction func indexChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
  let refreshAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Update", message: "Sure you wanna change this?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

  refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in

  }))

  refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
      // Nothing
  }))

  present(refreshAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to keep a variable that holds the last selected index. On completion handler of cancel , set your segment's selected index to the variable's value. On Ok's completion handler update the variable with the current selected index.